# A manga where the protagonist's power comes from a "mole" on his face

Tags: yakuza-girl

It's a fantasy/horror/fighting manga.

The protagonist goes to this school surrounded with a giant wall, which is for people with sort of weird powers.

Overtime, he develops a power, which is basically a 'mole' on his face but is super strong and can help him regenerate limbs and do stuff, etc.

There is also a girl who is with him all the time. From what I remember, she wears glasses, is quite quiet to begin with and fights with a katana/sword.

If any of you can tell me what this manga is, it would be great as I would like to read it again.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly [YAKUZA GIRL](http://myanimelist.net/manga/10347/Yakuza_Girl).

> Senguu Fumihiro is a young boy that made a promise to his dying grandmother to find a good wife for himself. With this intention he enrolls in a prestigious school but on the first day his world turns upside down when all the students begin to kill each other and one of them even turns into a monster. He is saved by a girl named "Akari" sent by one of the factions that rule the school to protect him.

Below is a picture of him getting said mole:

[image: Senguu notices he got a new mole]